# wordpress post the_content filter

Tags: wordpress, filter, pagination

I want write function which add to my post content `<!--nextpage-->` tags, I write this function:

```
<?php
function output($content) {
$output = $content.'<!--nextpage-->'.$content;

return $output;
}

add_filter('the_content','output');

?>
```

Function add `<!--nextpage-->` tags, but this tags not works when I display posts, it are like html comments, maybe are some solution to solve this problem ?

Maybe I must use not `the_content` but `wp_insert_post_data` ?

Comment: What do you mean does not work? What is it supposed to do? You are right that that's an HTML comment so it will not show up in your browser. Also your code is odd, basically what you're doing to duplicating the text you have and separating the two exact copies with your tag...

Comment: It must add post pogination, but tag `<!--nextpage-->` being dsplayed like html comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conversion from text with `<!--nextpage-->` into "pages" happens in `setup_postdata`. But the hook you use executes when the template tag with the same name, `the_content` is called. So what this means is you have to change the content before the loop starts. It can be a bit tricky. Off the top of my head I don't know of any suitable hooks but you can check the source code for `setup_postdata` and there might be one. In the theme, though, you can access `$posts` so if you put this in a template, it should work:

```
global $posts;
array_map( function( $apost ) {
    $apost->post_content = $apost->post_content.'<!--nextpage-->'.$apost->post_content;
    return $apost;
}, $posts );
```

If you don't have PHP version => 5.3 you can't use anonymous functions. In that case, this version will work:

```
global $posts;
function output( $apost ) {
    $apost->post_content = $apost->post_content.'<!--nextpage-->'.$apost->post_content;
    return $apost;
}
array_map( 'output', $posts );
```